# module 'hmac' has no attribute 'new'

Tags: python-3.x, hmac

Python version 3.7.3

I am using the HMAC module. When I try to run this code

```
digest = hmac.new(s.decode("base64"), a, digestmod=hashlib.sha3_256).digest()
```

The module hmac also has a .digest function. when I run either .new or .digest I get this error:

> digest = hmac.new(s.decode("base64"), a,
>
> digestmod=hashlib.sha3_256).digest()
>
> AttributeError: module 'hmac' has no attribute 'new'

When I run:

```
pip install hmac
```

I also get this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/empirestrikesback/PythonProjects/practice/aPI/envAPI/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/7v/cp_nrj9x4w13179t2t0h61cm0000gn/T/pip-install-kdd8dbs1/hashlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/7v/cp_nrj9x4w13179t2t0h61cm0000gn/T/pip-install-kdd8dbs1/hashlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/7v/cp_nrj9x4w13179t2t0h61cm0000gn/T/pip-install-kdd8dbs1/hashlib/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/7v/cp_nrj9x4w13179t2t0h61cm0000gn/T/pip-install-kdd8dbs1/hashlib/
    Complete output (22 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/empirestrikesback/PythonProjects/practice/aPI/envAPI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "/Users/empirestrikesback/PythonProjects/practice/aPI/envAPI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "/Users/empirestrikesback/PythonProjects/practice/aPI/envAPI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "/Users/empirestrikesback/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
        from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
      File "/Users/empirestrikesback/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
        from email._policybase import compat32
      File "/Users/empirestrikesback/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
        from email.utils import _has_surrogates
      File "/Users/empirestrikesback/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
        import random
      File "/Users/empirestrikesback/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 46, in <module>
        from hashlib import sha512 as _sha512
      File "/private/var/folders/7v/cp_nrj9x4w13179t2t0h61cm0000gn/T/pip-install-kdd8dbs1/hashlib/hashlib.py", line 80
        raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I assume it is not recognizing the module for some reason. My intention is to run an HMAC function with a message, secret, using SHA256.

Comment: Have you tried `hmac.HMAC(s.decode("base64"), a, digestmod=hashlib.sha3_256).digest()`

Comment: I gives the same error: AttributeError: module 'hmac' has no attribute 'HMAC'

Comment: in the python terminal can you try just `import hmac` then type just `hmac` to see the location of hmacand be sure its using the python in built hmac or some other bespoke version. for me i get `<module 'hmac' from 'C:\\Users\\cd00119621\\.virtualenvs\\stackoverflow-yoix_gHB\\lib\\hmac.py'>` and if then look in this file i can search for `def new` and see the method

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I think you helped solved the issue. I had created my own hmac.py file in my directory which was being imported instead of the lib package hmac.py. The problem seems to be solved now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah glad you got it sorted. Do you want me to write an answer just for completeness of the question

Comment: @ChrisDoyle you have solved the problem. You suggestion to see the file led me to find that it was in fact calling a file I created hmac.py in the same directory of my application instead of importing the hmac.py from home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/hmac.py. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, please. If you can write the answer more explicitly it will definitely assist people like myself still fairly new to navigating this environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments it seems you have found the issue. You have created a file in your local dir called hmac.py. In your other script when you call `import hmac` python will find the hmac.py in your local dir not the one thats in the lib dir of your python install.

This means that your not actually loading pythons hmac library but instead your loading your own hmac.py script which doesnt have a new or digest method.

The lesson hear is dont call your own files with names that may conflict with pythons or thrid party modules unless you are specifically trying to implement your own version of the module.